# Correctly implementing the Facebook Like button

Tags: images, facebook, open-graph

As per documentation I satisfied all the requirements of the like button by using the meta-tags, however I still don't get the image I would like linked by Facebook: it always goes fishing for another image in the sidebar.

Now, of course I could solve this by being explicit about which image I really want but I do I get that image from Wordpress? Is there a function like post_image() that would print its URL like there is for the permalink?

Thanks

Comment: @L. De Leo: Can you post your current code? PHP code and the HTML it generates. Or can you point us to a live site that shows the problem?

Comment: I've noticed something strange: when I share something to Facebook by clicking the Like on my site it gets the wrong image. When instead I post the link in my status on Facebook the correct image is presented as the first option.

Answer (score 2):

Yoast.com actually covered this quite recently...

```
if (  is_singular() ) {
  global $post;
  if ( current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails') 
      && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
      get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail', false);
    echo '<meta property="og:image" 
      content="'.$thumbnail[0].'" />';  
  }
  echo '<meta property="og:title" 
    content="'.get_the_title().'" />';
  if ( get_the_excerpt() != '' )
    echo '<meta property="og:description" 
      content="'.strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ).'" />';
}
```

Explanation and more details are here: http://yoast.com/facebook-share-wordpress/

Comment: Joost is the best, god bless him! ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( i tried to create a thumbnail but nothing

Comment: What doesn't work? I haven't played around with this very much myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample from a recent project. This sets the OpenGraph properties for a specific post. Add the code to the header.

```
<?php if (is_single()) { // Display only on single posts ?>
<?php $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); 
// Optionally, use the code below (untested) to get a thumbnail based on a specific thumbnail size
// $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'custom-thumbnail-name'); 
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumbnail_url[0]; ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Website Name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="732866210" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used FB OpenGraph meta tags (as Jonathan wrote) on one of my websites, and it works, but not always. Sometimes, the thumbnail still is another image on the site. Then I found the `link` tag that is working for me:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg" />
```

I'm using both methods now (`link` and `meta` tags), and the thumbnail shown on FB is always correct!

After implement any methods, you should use [this tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to check it out. If should show correct title, description and thumbnail.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook) is another topic you might interested in.